# How can I adapt a Dell 2001FP stand for use on newer Dell monitors?

Tags: display, lcd

I find myself really disappointed with how little vertical adjustment newer Dell LCD's have.  I am retiring a malfunctioning Dell 2001FP.  The stand on the 2001FP allows over 6 inches of vertical adjustment.  Compare this to my newer monitors, a 2005FP and a SW22209, both of which allow at most 2 inches of vertical adjustment.

So while the Dell 2001FP monitor is shot, the stand is not.  Is there anyway to fit the stand onto the SW2209 or the 2005FP?

The 2001FP stand seems to have an odd plate with three tabs on the top edge.  Can I replace this?

Comment: I've got a pair of 2001FPs and they're starting to show signs of age. I'm not looking forward to replacing them for this very reason - I can adjust their height to perfection, something I've not been able to do with newer, "more advanced" monitors.

Comment: Yeah, its ridiculous how high the stand will go - I love it.  From Jakobud's answer below I think that cutting off that middle tab and then shave down the inside edge of the remaining four tabs would have it fit in either of the two above monitors.  The only concern is structural integrity and if there is any wobbling.  If this works I would be tempted to buy another 2001FP stand to match the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced my old 24" Dell Ultrasharp stand with the newer 24" Ultrasharp stand. It basically required a drill, dremel and some elbow-grease. Just modified the old mount to fit the new stand. There didn't seem to be any way to replace just the plate that the old mount was on.

I'd imagine you will need to do something similar. It's not simple but its not impossible.

Comment: Care to comment on the purpose of your mod - do you prefer the new mount to the old?

Comment: No better answer yet and this answer confirms that a tools + willingness will get the job done.